# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to read a text file line by line as integers. I did every suggestion I saw here but none works for me. here is the code I'm using. It reads some seismic data from the datadir and evaluates the SNR ratio to decide whether keep the data or remove it. To do so, I need to calculate the distance between stations and the earthquake which the info comes from input files.

```
from obspy import UTCDateTime
import os

datadir = "/home/alireza/Desktop/Saman/Eqcomplete"
homedir = "/home/alireza/Desktop/Saman"

eventlist = os.path.join (homedir, 'events.dat')
stationlist = os.path.join (homedir, 'all_st')

e = open (eventlist, "r")
for event in e.readlines():
    year, mon, day, time, lat, lon = event.split (" ")
    h = str (time.split (":")[0])   # hour
    m = str (time.split (":")[1])   # minute
    s = str (time.split (":")[2])   # second

    s = open (stationlist, "r")
    for station in s.readlines():
        stname, stlo, stla = station.split (" ")
        OafterB = UTCDateTime (int(year), int(mon), int(day), int(h), int(m), int(s))
        print (OafterB)     # just to have an output!
    s.close ()
e.close ()`
```

- Update:
- There are two input files:

1. events.dat  which is like:

```
2020 03 18 17:45:39 -11.0521 115.1378
```

2. all_st   which is like:

```
  AHWZ 48.644 31.430
  AFRZ 59.015 33.525
  NHDN 60.050 31.493
  BDRS 48.881 34.054
  BMDN 48.825 33.772
  HAGD 49.139 34.922
```

Here is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SNR.py", line 21, in <module>
    OafterB = UTCDateTime (int(year), int(mon), int(day), int(h), int(m), int(s))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'
```

Here to test the code you need to install the obspy package.
`pip install obspy` may work.

Comment: did you debug? what are the values in h, m, s variables?

Comment: I tried everything I knew. I am not an expert in python. h, m, and s are hour, minute, and second. you can see the example input.

Comment: I don't see how this error could be caused by the code you've shown. It sounds like maybe you supplied a file object to `int()`. Can you provide the full stack trace, not just the bare error message? (Also, your code as shown isn't testable alone. Please read over what's expected of a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).)

Comment: Including the rest of your code does make your example complete and runnable, so good job on that. But it's far from minimal... that's a lot of code unrelated to your problem for others to wade through in trying to help you. I'd recommend trying either of the two methods described under "Minimal" on the [MRE page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Bonus: it'll also help you get better at debugging.

Comment: Update: I can't reproduce this error with the code and sample data posted. It's possible it somehow involves other parts of your data files. Did you test your code with this specific subset to see if it still generates the error?

Comment: Sorry, my very first time posting here. Please see the updated code

Comment: That is much more streamlined, good job! But running it with your example data still doesn't reproduce the error on my end, so I'm not sure what to tell you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting the same error using the example code and data! You mean you can see the printed values of OafterB parameter?

Comment: Oh wait, my apologies. I mistakenly ran your previous version again (from before the edit), which runs fine on my end because I have no data files. One moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `s` here:

```
s = str (time.split (":")[2])   # second
```

But then, immediately afterward, you refine it:

```
s = open (stationlist, "r")
```

Now `s` points to a file object, so `int(s)` fails with the above error. Name your station list file object something different, and the problem goes away.

---

Other tips which you may find helpful:

- [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) will automatically split on whitespace unless you tell it otherwise, so there's no need to specify `" "`.
- You can use multiple assignment to assign `h`, `m`, and `s` the same way you did with the previous line. Currently, you're performing the same split operation three different times.
- It's recommended to open files using the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) keyword, which will automatically handle closing the file, even if an exception occurs.
- You can iterate over a file object directly, without creating a list with `readlines()`.
- Using [pathlib](https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/) can make it much simpler and cleaner to deal with filesystem paths and separators.
- It's considered bad form to put spaces between the name of a function and the parentheses.
- There's also a convention that variable names (other than class names) are usually all lowercase, with underscores between words as needed. *(See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for a helpful rundown of all such style conventions. They're not hard and fast rules, but they can help make code more consistent and readable.)*

With those things in mind, here's a slightly spruced up version of your above code:

```
from pathlib import Path
from obspy import UTCDateTime

data_dir = Path('/home/alireza/Desktop/Saman/Eqcomplete')
home_dir = Path('/home/alireza/Desktop/Saman')

event_list = home_dir / 'events.dat'
station_list = home_dir / 'all_st'

with open(event_list) as e_file:
    for event in e_file:
        year, mon, day, time, lat, lon = event.split()
        h, m, s = time.split(':')

        with open(station_list) as s_file:
            for station in s_file:
                stname, stlo, stla = station.split()
                o_after_b = UTCDateTime(
                    int(year), int(mon), int(day), int(h), int(m), int(s)
                )
                print(o_after_b)
```

Comment: Thank you for saving my time and for the instructions.